# Expo - ImagePicker aspect on iOS not working. Square only

Tags: react-native, expo

The imagePicker component works well on both iOS and Android.

The aspect ratio works perfectly on android however doesn't work on iOS. I am using create-react-native-app and I don't want to eject and use another package.

I need to create three cropping options - Landscape, Square and Portrait. Right now I can only get square images.

I get square dimensions for width and height when taking a picture from the camera but getting the original image dimensions when selecting from gallery.

I'm using a sample piece of code. Let me know what can be done to fix this please or another package I could use to achieve this without ejecting. Many thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ImagePicker, Permissions, Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
state = {
result: null,
};

askPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    // you would probably do something to verify that permissions
    // are actually granted, but I'm skipping that for brevity
};

useLibraryHandler = async () => {
    await this.askPermissionsAsync();
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [12, 3],
        base64: false,
    });
    console.log(result.width, result.height, "result");
    this.setState({ result });
};

useCameraHandler = async () => {
    await this.askPermissionsAsync();
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [12, 3],
        base64: false,
    });
    console.log(result.width, result.height, "result");
    this.setState({ result });
};

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <Button title="launchCameraAsync" onPress={this.useCameraHandler} />
            <Button
                title="launchImageLibraryAsync"
                onPress={this.useLibraryHandler}
            />
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                {JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}
            </Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You'll be returned with only **square image** in **IOS***

As mentioned in the expo [docs](https://github.com/expo/expo-docs/blob/master/versions/v19.0.0/sdk/imagepicker.md).

**aspect (array)** -- An array with two entries `[x, y]` specifying the aspect ratio to maintain if the user is allowed to edit the image (by passing `allowsEditing: true`).

> This is only applicable on **Android**, since on **iOS** **the crop rectangle** is always a **square**.

Therefore you need to manually resize the image by using [**react-native-image-resizer**](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer) or any other alternative packages.

Comment: I read this over and over again. I can't believe I missed this. Really sorry! Could you just explain to me whether the cropper window can be fixed to a widescreen format using this package? Or is it just using a square cropper window and resizing the output image after it has been cropped? Could you also explain to me how this can be done if possible? Thanks